# Enabling GPS and location settings permanently on LTE modem in Linux, and integrating with gpsd

Tags: laptop, gpsd

I can enable GPS on my LTE modem using `mmcli --location-enable-gps-raw` and get the current location with `mmcli --location-get`.
How I can enable the location settings permanently (except starting `mmcli --location-enable-gps-raw` in a startup script)? And: is there a way to use the gps data to use with `gpsd`? `mmcli` has the option `gps-unmanaged`, but it is not supported (Dell DW5820e L850-GL)

```
$ mmcli -m 0 --location-enable-gps-unmanaged 
error: couldn't setup location gathering: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unsupported: Cannot enable unsupported location sources: 'gps-unmanaged''
```